# what is the max number of nodes in rethinkdb?

Tags: rethinkdb

I've read on rethinkdb's doc that we can have a number of nodes from one to sixteen but actually I don't know if it is a way of speaking or a real limit.
I launched 20 VirtualBox VMs to create a cluster and I found troubles to have all nodes in the cluster online at the same time, 3 or 4 nodes loose connectivity. This makes sense with the 16 limit but I havent found similar limits for other nosql databases.
Is 16 a real maximum number of nodes per cluster limit on rethinkdb?
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is: There is no hard limit.

It is written 16 machines because that is what we have tested so far.
Some tests have been run with 64 nodes and while it doesn't scale as much as it should, it still works.
RethinkDB is aiming for a smooth experience with 100 servers and 100.000 tables -- see https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/1861 to track progress.

Also if you run 20 VMs on the same machine, the host may not have enough resources to run the cluster, which would explains the timeouts.

Comment: I modified VMs' config and I've no problems with 20 nodes at same time.